# How to get rich-text within a group from Prismic

Tags: prismic.io

In Prismic I have a rich-text field inside a group that I want to retrieve as HTML. I can retrieve the data but can't retrieve it as HTML. How can I query this to get it back as HTML? There's no example of that in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in a foreach loop that loops through all entries in your group. Then the RichText::asHtml should work.

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item):?>
<a href="#"><?= RichText::asHtml($item->text_block_in_your_group ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```